# How to get a path of a folder in cloudera?

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera

Im trying to run a my code in java using hadoop but I get an error of the path of the file

```
 scanner1 = new Scanner(new File("/home/cloudera/pos.txt")); //Path
```

The error message that I get is:

`Status : FAILED
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/cloudera/pos.txt (Permission denied)`

Comment: `File` is a Java object for working with files on the local file system. It is not how you access files on HDFS.

Answer (score 2):

The "Permission denied" in the error message indicates you don't have read access to the directory.  Which user is running the java code, your personal user or the cloudera?  To fix, you should either make the data readable for your user, move it to a common location that is globally readable, think /usr/local, or run your code as the cloudera user.  Also, is this in HDFS or on the local filesystem?

Comment: @mwedster I'm a cloudera user and it is in HDFS

Comment: Sorry, I may not have been clear, from the output it appears you are trying to read data from an hdfs directory that the linux user named 'cloudera' owns.  Can you run `hadoop fs -ls /home/cloudera` and paste the output.